# How do I install catdoc via homebrew?

Tags: terminal, install, homebrew

I wanted to install catdoc on my Mac Sierra system. I was following the link here: [brewformulas.org/Catdoc](http://brewformulas.org/Catdoc), but when I run the commands I get an `No available formula with the name "catdoc"` error. Below is the complete output.

```
localhost:tmp davea$ brew install catdoc
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 3 taps (caskroom/cask, homebrew/core, phinze/cask).
==> New Formulae
akamai         apng2gif       bash-snippets  dep            glpk           hdf5           metis          openblas       qhull          r              scalapack      snapcraft      veclibfort
apache-ctakes  arpack         bento4         ghc@8.0        goose          maven@3.0      octave         pumba          qrupdate       redis@3.2      sccache        suite-sparse
==> Updated Formulae
acpica                       crowdin                      glew                         languagetool                 mysql                        platformio                   swiftformat
aescrypt-packetizer          cryptol                      gnatsd                       launch4j                     mysql-cluster                plplot                       swiftlint
afl-fuzz                     crystal-lang                 gnome-builder                lean-cli                     mysql-connector-c            ponyc                        swiftplate
afsctool                     cython                       gnome-recipes                ledit                        mysql-sandbox                poppler ✔                    syncthing
agda                         dbhash                       gnu-chess                    leveldb                      mysql@5.5                    ppsspp                       syntaxerl
allure                       dbt                          gnupg ✔                      lftp                         mysql@5.6                    pqiv                         sysdig
amazon-ecs-cli               dbus                         gnupg-pkcs11-scd             libarchive                   nano                         pre-commit                   t1utils
ammonite-repl                dcm2niix                     gnupg@1.4                    libcds                       ncmpc                        presto                       talloc
angular-cli                  dcos-cli                     gnuplot                      libfreenect                  ncmpcpp                      protobuf-swift               tarsnap-gui
ansifilter                   dependency-check             goad                         libgcrypt                    neo4j                        psqlodbc                     tcl-tk
apache-arrow                 depqbf                       gobject-introspection ✔      libgit2-glib                 netpbm                       pulseaudio                   tcpdump
apache-geode                 dhall-json                   gofabric8                    libhttpseverywhere           nmap                         pushpin                      tee-clc
apktool                      diff-pdf                     google-benchmark             libmpdclient                 nnn                          pwntools                     telegraf
app-engine-go-64             diff-so-fancy                gource                       libmwaw                      node                         pyenv                        teleport
arangodb                     diffoscope                   gradle                       libphonenumber               node-build                   pyenv-virtualenv             termius
artifactory                  digdag                       grafana                      libpng ✔                     node@4                       pygobject                    terraform
arx-libertatis               django-completion            grakn                        libpst                       node@6                       pygobject3                   terragrunt
ascii                        dmd                          groonga                      libqalculate                 nodeenv                      pyinvoke                     tfenv
aspell                       dmtx-utils                   gsmartcontrol                librdkafka                   nomad                        pyqt                         thefuck
assimp                       dnsmasq                      gsoap                        librsvg                      notmuch                      python ✔                     tika
aws-sdk-cpp                  docker-compose               gst-editing-services         libsodium                    nsd                          python3                      tippecanoe
awscli                       docker-compose-completion    gst-libav                    libtiff ✔                    nspr                         qemu                         tomcat
awslogs                      docutils                     gst-plugins-bad              libtorrent-rasterbar         numpy                        qscintilla2                  tor
axel                         dub                          gst-plugins-base             libvirt                      nuxeo                        rakudo-star                  trafficserver
bacula-fd                    duck                         gst-plugins-good             libwps                       nzbget                       rclone                       translate-toolkit
bartycrouch                  eg                           gst-plugins-ugly             libxkbcommon                 ocaml                        re2                          twoping
basex                        elasticsearch                gst-python                   linkerd                      ocamlbuild                   reattach-to-user-namespace   typescript
bazel                        elasticsearch@2.4            gst-rtsp-server              log4cpp                      ocamlsdl                     rebar@3                      unison
bibtex2html                  elixir                       gst-validate                 logstalgia                   ola                          recoverjpeg                  unison@2.40
bind                         emscripten                   gstreamer                    logstash                     one-ml                       redis ✔                      unrar
binutils                     encfs                        gtk+3                        logtalk                      oniguruma                    redis-leveldb                urh
blastem                      etcd                         h2                           lolcat                       opam                         rethinkdb                    v8@3.15
blockhash                    etsh                         harfbuzz                     lxc                          openal-soft                  rlvm                         varnish
bmake                        evince                       haskell-stack                macvim ✔                     openclonk                    rocksdb                      varnish@4
brew-gem                     expat                        haste-client                 makensis                     opencsg                      rom-tools                    vim ✔
btfs                         exploitdb                    haxe                         mal4s                        openmsx                      roswell                      vim@7.4
buku                         fabio                        hbase                        mame                         openrtsp                     rtags                        vimpc
byobu                        ffmpeg                       heimdal                      mariadb                      opensc                       rtv                          vips
cabal-install                fibjs                        heroku                       mat                          openshift-cli                ruby-build ✔                 voldemort
caddy                        filebeat                     hevea                        mediaconch                   openvdb                      rust                         vowpal-wabbit
cake                         firebase-cli                 highlight                    mednafen                     opusfile                     saltstack                    wabt
camlp4                       fizsh                        htmldoc                      memcached ✔                  orc                          sane-backends                watchman
camlp5                       flake8                       httpflow                     menhir                       orientdb                     sbcl                         watson
cargo-completion             flawfinder                   hydra                        meson                        osc                          sbt                          webdis
catimg                       flow                         hyperscan                    mesos                        osm2pgsql                    scala                        webpack
certbot                      fluent-bit                   idris                        metabase                     osquery                      scalaenv                     whois
certstrap                    fobis                        imagemagick ✔                metricbeat                   osrm-backend                 scalariform                  widelands
chakra                       folly                        imagemagick@6                mftrace                      owfs                         scipy                        wimlib
checkstyle                   fontforge                    immortal                     mgba                         oysttyer                     scw                          wine
chromedriver                 fonttools                    infer                        micro                        packer                       shadowsocks-libev            wiredtiger
citus                        forego                       influxdb                     miller                       packetbeat                   sip                          wireguard-tools
clojurescript                format-udf                   influxdb@0.8                 mingw-w64                    packetq                      sjk                          wireshark
closure-stylesheets          freeradius-server            ircii                        minimal-racket               paket                        skinny                       woboq_codebrowser
cmake                        fs-uae                       jags                         minio                        pango                        snakemake                    wpscan
cmark                        fstar                        jboss-forge                  mkvtoolnix                   parallel                     snap-telemetry               x265
coccinelle                   fzf                          jenkins                      mldonkey                     pari                         snappy                       xapian
cockroach                    gdk-pixbuf                   jenkins-lts                  mobile-shell                 passenger ✔                  snzip                        xdot
cocoapods                    gearman                      jfrog-cli-go                 monax                        pdf2htmlex                   softhsm                      xsv
codec2                       gedit                        jhipster                     monetdb                      pdf2json                     sparkey                      yarn
coffeescript                 geos                         jmxtrans                     mongo-orchestration          pdftoedn                     sqldiff                      yaz
collector-sidecar            geoserver                    jsdoc3                       mosquitto                    pdftoipe                     sqlite ✔                     yle-dl
commandbox                   get-flash-videos             juju                         mpc                          percona-server               sqlite-analyzer              you-get
compcert                     getdns                       kibana                       mpd                          percona-server-mongodb       sqlmap                       youtube-dl
conan                        getmail                      knot                         mpdas                        percona-server@5.5           sslyze                       zabbix
consul                       ghc                          knot-resolver                mpg123                       percona-server@5.6           ssreflect                    zbar
convmv                       git ✔                        kobalt                       mpv                          percona-toolkit              stella                       zero-install
convox                       git-extras                   kompose                      msgpack                      percona-xtrabackup           stunnel                      zsh-completions
coq                          git-flow-avh                 kops                         msitools                     pgbadger                     supertux
corectl                      git-fresh                    kubernetes-cli               mspdebug                     pgcli                        supervisor
cppcheck                     gitlab-ci-multi-runner       kubernetes-helm              mycli                        pioneer                      suricata
cromwell                     gjs                          lablgtk                      mypy                         planck                       swagger-codegen
==> Renamed Formulae
transfig -> fig2dev

Error: No available formula with the name "catdoc"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

What am I missing regarding how to install catdoc via homebrew?

Answer (score 8):

Catdoc isn't available in any homebrew repository. It has never been part of the core formula repo:

```
MyiMac:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula [git::master]
> git pull
Already up-to-date.
Current branch master is up to date.

MyiMac:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula [git::master]
> git log -- ./catdoc.rb

MyiMac:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula [git::master]
>
```

So you have to download, compile and install it yourself from source in homebrew.

Create a catdoc.rb with the following content:

```
require 'formula'

class Catdoc < Formula  
  url 'http://ftp.wagner.pp.ru/pub/catdoc/catdoc-0.95.tar.gz'
  homepage 'http://wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/'
  sha256 '514a84180352b6bf367c1d2499819dfa82b60d8c45777432fa643a5ed7d80796'  

  def install    

  # catdoc configure says it respects --mandir=, but does not.    
  ENV['man1dir'] = man1
  system "./configure --disable-debug --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=#{prefix}"    

  # The INSTALL file confuses make on case insensitive filesystems.    
  system "mv INSTALL INSTALL.txt"
  system "make"    

  # There is a race condition in the charsets/Makefile install target. The following line solves it.    
  system "make -C charsets install-dirs"   
  system "make install"  
  end
end
```

and install it in the homebrew environment with:

```
brew install --build-from-source catdoc.rb
```

Comment: @IanC. Apparently it was part of homebrew(-core?) but landed in some [boneyard](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-boneyard/commit/98b68c6b34a8d55caffd418c4940b397a60178ce#diff-732fd48a514d0c03b4c3297bcb3698bf)...

Comment: Weird. I don't know what gets something relegated to the boneyard like that.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is not what you are after, but if you have [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) installed, it seems to be available there.  Because I don't like managing installs myself, if Homebrew doesn't have something, those are my backups.

The caveat about having multiple package managers is that you might be asked to install certain dependencies that you already have, thus having multiple dependencies from different package manages in different locations.